# FileStream, only producing one result?

Tags: c#, filestream

I have two filestreams which collects different information from different files:

```
FileStream dataStruc = new FileStream("c:\\temp\\dataStruc.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);

FileStream csvFile = new FileStream("c:\\temp\\" + fileName + ".txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);

StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(csvFile);
StreamWriter swc = new StreamWriter(dataStruc);
```

when both streamwriters are used to get the same piece of information like shown below:

```
sw.WriteLine(sheet); 
swc.WriteLine(sheet);
```

then `sw` streamwriter has information from file. Have I set up my filestreams incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you don't get any exceptions/errors and that basic stuff like the correct path for the `csvFile` FileStream is verified and found to be correct: Try adding a [`Flush()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.flush.aspx) or propery closing the stream using [`Close()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.close). Even better: use a [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) statement.

**EDIT**
After reading your question again: are you sure you just didn't switch the filestreams?

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(csvFile);
StreamWriter swc = new StreamWriter(dataStruc);
```

as opposed to

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(dataStruc);
StreamWriter swc = new StreamWriter(csvFile);
```

Your question and description is rather vague: "*both streamwriters are used to get the same piece of information*". How would stream **writers** be used to **get** information? Also: "*sw streamwriter has information from file*": could you be more specific? This doesn't make sense.

Whatever the case may be; use the debugger luke!

Comment: thank you so much for your help, all that was needed was the flush() method on one of the streamwriters. thanks

Comment: Actually, you might need it on both. And even better: you should probably be using the [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you have conflicting **concurrent** access to the file by both StreamWriters.

You open the streams with `FileMode.Create`. See the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode.aspx) (highlights by me):

> Specifies that the operating system should create a new file. **If the
>   file already exists, it will be overwritten**. This operation requires
>   FileIOPermissionAccess.Write permission. System.IO.FileMode.Create is
>   equivalent to requesting that if the file does not exist, use
>   CreateNew; **otherwise, use Truncate**.

I am not sure if the second `StreamWriter`, depending on the order of the initialization, overwrites the file of the first `StreamWriter` or simply fails. Either way, they do try conflicting work.

Possible solutions:

- Make sure the streams access the file only one after the other, e.g. by closing the first stream before the second one accesses the file, e.g. with a [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) block.
- Change the `FileMode` on the streams so that an existing file does not get overridden if possible. (See the documentation above.)

Comment: Ah, clever. It could, indeed, be the case that the variable `fileName` contains the value "`dataStruc`" in which case both writers would be writing to the same file. As long as not all code is posted (or at least the contents of the `fileName` variable is posted) it will be anyones guess I'm afraid.